No terminal commands being recognized in macOS Terminal using Zsh. How can I get them back?
None of my commands are working inside my macOS terminal. Usual commands like sudo, nano, vim, ls, cd, all are not working or being recognized.
They were working before however after adding flutter $PATH variable all commands stopped working.
Any way to get everything reset to default in the terminal or get these commands working again?

One possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69768619

macOS version? What is your $PATH?  echo $PATH.

As you say it yourself: You messed up your PATH. Of course, if you ruin your PATH you can't expect a peaceful life anymore. Hower in your question, you don't show how your PATH is actually set (do a print $path in your shell), so I can't advise anything.
